# Spring MVC redirect without parameters

Tags: java, spring, redirect, parameters, controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView loginPage(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user")User user, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {

    if(result.hasErrors()){
        model.addAttribute("failedLogin", "username or password is invalid");
    }

    if(loginService.authenticateUser(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword())){
        model.addAttribute("username", user.getUsername());
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/welcome");
    }
    else{
        return new ModelAndView("login/login");
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/welcome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String welcomePage(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user")User user, BindingResult result, ModelMap model){
    model.addAttribute("username", user.getUsername());
    return "login/welcome";
}
```

When I log in, I get '*http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/welcome?username=volkansahin*' while waiting '*http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/welcome*'

I cannot clean the model, but I using username parameter in JSP file.

Comment: `model.addAttribute("username", user.getUsername());`

Comment: What must do I here?

Comment: I thought you was trying to redirect to an other Controller.
loginPage method should be changed instead :

... 
loginPage(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user")User user, BindingResult result, ModelMap model, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    if(result.hasErrors()){
        model.addAttribute("failedLogin", "username or password is invalid");
    }

    if(loginService.authenticateUser(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword())){
       redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("username", user.getUsername());
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/welcome");
    }

Comment: I try to redirect for LoginController, not another controller.

Comment: URL is 'http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/welcome' but then I cannot access to username in JSP page when I do this.

Answer (score 4):

In Order to keep your attributes during Redirection, you have to use **RedirectAttributes**

like this :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/welcome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String welcomePage(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user")User user, BindingResult result, ModelMap model, **final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes**){
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("username", user.getUsername());
    return "login/welcome";
}
```

refer to this url for more informations about redirect attributes :
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html

Or follow this simple ex :

http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/redirect-attributes/

Comment: Then I can not access the jsp page.